# What is the meaning of the abbreviations “h.e.” and “h.l.”?

Tags: abbreviations

In *Novum Lexicon Graeco-Latinum in Novum Testamentum*, Johann Friedrich Schleusner wrote the following entry on the Greek word νεόφυτος.<sup>1</sup>

[image: Novum Lexicon Graeco-Latinum in Novum Testamentum, Vol. 2, p. 174]

In his entry, he uses two abbreviations, “h.e.” and “h.l.”

What are the meaning of those two abbreviations? (I’m guessing that “h.e.” stands for “hic est.”)

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> p. [174](https://books.google.com/books?id=dhVUAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA174&ots=G42bTPOH27&dq=%CE%BD%CE%B5%E1%BD%B9%CF%86%CF%85%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD%201%20tim.%203%3B6%20metaphor&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q&f=true)

### References

Schleusner, Johann Friedrich. [*Novum Lexicon Graeco-Latinum in Novum Testamentum.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dhVUAAAAcAAJ) Vol. 2. Leipzig: Weidmann, 1792.

Comment: See also [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14175/what-does-the-abbreviation-h-l-or-h-1-stand-for?rq=1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

h.e. = hoc est

ad h.l. = ad hunc locum

Comment: Is this a commonly accepted abbreviation? Do you know when it started?

Comment: @brianpck. I must admit to never have seen them before, but they are quite obvious from the context, don't you think? "NN ad locum" is common in scholastic Latin for "NN, in his commentary on this passage".

Comment: I agree, but presumably he's following some kind of convention? I was thrown off by *h.e.*, especially because *i.e. * is far more common

Comment: @brianpck. The Germans say "zu dieser Stelle" with the same technical meaning. I wonder whether the German is a calque on the Latin, or the other way round.

Comment: I know at least one living Latinist (that is, a Latinist who treats the language as a living one, not who is alive, though he is) who, when writing Latin, uses "h.e." where we today use "i.e."

Comment: Both seem to be found in many texts ([former](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22h.%20e.%22%20hoc%20est;a=srchls) and [later](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=%22ad%20h.%20l.%22;a=srchls)).