# what does the abbreviation "h. l." (or "h. 1.") stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

In one of the footnotes in Popma's book, we [read](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=22lpAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=%22Vocabulum%20hocce%20in%20genere%20neutro%22&source=bl&ots=ae2kgmF5s5&sig=ACfU3U10V5pAr1TeqjZ-RqXG1xN0TdW5Ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiStvO3z8TqAhWPqqQKHSZuBEoQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Vocabulum%20hocce%20in%20genere%20neutro%22&f=false):

> Vocabulum hocce in genere neutro **h. l.** esse positum, testatur Erythraeus in Ind. Virgil. fol. 41. fac. 2. col b.

I could not find Erythraeu's book itself to see if **"h. l"** occurs there also, or this "h. l" is related to the citation (but as the full citation comes later, it seem quite improbable).

**Edit**  : in the following footnote we find also "h. e", that's too I could not decipher, but they might be related.

Comment: See also [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-abbreviations-h-e-and-h-l).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The abbreviation *h. l.* [means](https://books.google.de/books?id=t3fLBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA482#v=onepage&q&f=false) **hoc loco** – “here, in this place, in this instance.” This is a common abbreviation which you can find in various books.

The abbreviation *h. e.* [probably means](https://books.google.de/books?id=v1AMAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA845#v=onepage&q&f=false) **hoc est** or possibly **hic est** (some sources on Google Books prefer the latter, although I do not see why) – the meaning being more or less the same as the more well-known *id est* = “that is, that is to say.”

Comment: Thanks! can you link one of the Google Books dictionary sources for abbreviation? for some reason they evade me.

Comment: @d_e I have added links; the best way to find abbreviations on Google Books I am afraid is *guessing* the meaning first, then searching for the unabbreviated term.

Answer (score 1):

**Erythraeus and his Index of Virgil**
'Publii Virgilii Maronis Bucolica, Georgica, et Aeneis, nunc demum ...,' Volume 2 By Nicolaus Erythraeus is published as an open access Google e-book.
Page 41 covers words beginning Cl; and sure enough 'Clypeum' is listed in preference to 'Clypeus' (on the right hand leaf).